# Is $\mathbb Z_4$ a UFD (unique factorization domain)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

> Is  $\mathbb Z_4$ a UFD (unique factorization domain) ?

I know that $\mathbb Z_4$ is not a field, as $\mathbb Z$ is not a field  but $\mathbb Z$ is a UFD, so $\mathbb Z_4$ is also UFD...

Is my thinking is correct or not ?

Comment: Hint: what is $2 \cdot 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

Comment: It's not even an *integral domain*.

Comment: @Krish you are right, I was searching for this only. whether any text defines UFD for a non integral domain. In Wikipedia, J.A Gallian, everywhere UFD defines for an integral domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be a UFD it must be an integral domain. If $n$ is not prime, ask yourself, what equivalence class do the product of the factors of $n$ land in inside $\mathbf{Z}_n$?